# Inverter o tamanho da caixa das letras - VISUALG

Tags: algoritmo, portugol, visualg

estou com um problema, em programação de algoritmos em visualG.
preciso inverter um array com valores atribuídos a ele.

```
// opcao 18
funcao menu_18():caractere
var
inicio
escreval (" A ORDEM INVERSA É: ")
para contador de 12 ate 0 faca
     escreva(" ", c[contador])
fimpara
escreval(" ")
fimfuncao
```

onde os valores de contador vao de 0 ate 12, com caracteres atribuidos a eles, mas preciso imprimir o inverso deles.

exemplo `(" A B C ")`

```
saída: (" C B A ")
```

qual seria a melhor resolução para este problema?

Comment: Oi @AGenaro tente usar passo -1 no laço que vai ir certinho!

Answer (score 1):

```
escreval (" A ORDEM INVERSA É: ")
para contador de 12 ate 0 faca
     escreva(c[contador])
fimpara
```

Este trecho está certo, confirme se seu vetor é [0..12], veja se você está atribuindo corretamente os valores ao vetor, não sei se você está definindo os valores no próprio código ou se está lendo do teclado, mas de qualquer forma, é provável que se esteja com algum problema é na hora de atribuir os dados no vetor.

Comment: Não precisa por o passo -1?